Running fully sheathed romex through a media box
In a living room, I need to run some Romex up to a new outlet location in the same stud bay as an outlet lower down. But there's a Media Enclosure box in the way that takes up 100% of the space (width + depth) of that stud bay, so the only direct path for the Romex is to go through (aka inside) that box, not beside or behind it. The only alternative would be to take a detour through an adjacent stud bay, but this would require a bunch of drywall repair that I'd rather avoid.
As far as I understand it, I can run the Romex through the media box as long as I leave it sheathed. To be clear, the romex won't be stripped or terminated within the media box, and no splices or devices will be installed inside the media box. I believe this would still be up to code, since the Romex will be sufficiently protected from physical damage because of the studs on both sides of the media box, and the media box can pretty much be ignored.
Is this correct? Also, given the romex will remain in its sheath the whole time, do I need to care about the presence of low-voltage wiring in that media box?

What's inside this media box?

A bunch of low voltage stuff -- networking, a/v, etc..

I am pretty sure this is fine. It shouldn't be different from running Romex through a cabinet (e.g., kitchen or bath or whatever), where the only real concern is protection from damage. The issue with low voltage and mains voltage in the same box is with the possibility of things being electrically mixed together, which should not be an issue with a clean sealed section of Romex.

I know of nothing that states this cannot be done. I have seen transformers energized in media cabinets and have also seen outlets installed in them. You would still have to use the proper connectors entering and leaving the cabinet though.


You would still have to use the proper connectors entering and leaving the cabinet though.
Why? I'm not terminating the cable into this cabinet, and so I don't think I need strain relief. The cables will be terminated into a proper electric box outside that panel, and will have proper NM-B clamp connectors there for strain relief.


I'm referring to the metal media cabinets where the knockouts have the sharp edges and the connectors are there to protect the cables.

Got it, thanks for clarifying!

No different than NB running straight through a junction box with no splicing,  connectors needed entering and leaving.

Understood. If this is a plastic media box with large knockouts that aren't particularly sharp, would you still install connectors?

I guess that would depend on the actual cabinet. Plastic  cabinets I've seen have some sort of molded connector device like the plastic junction boxes for electric wiring.

It doesn't hurt to use connectors apart from the few bucks they may cost, but with electrical, it's always better to be safe than sorry.
